# Conditional probability for 4 events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Alice tries for 4 job interviews A,B,C,D with the probabilities to pass the interviews

$Pr[A]=0.1$

$Pr[B]=0.2$

$Pr[C]=0.3$

$Pr[D]=0.4$

There are no dependence to get accepted for different interviews.

Alice will try the 4 interviews inorder and will stop when she succeeds in two.

If Alice has succeeded in interview C ,what is the probability for Alice to do the D interview?

I thought of using Bayes rule for two events $Pr[D|C]=\frac{Pr[C|D]\cdot Pr[D]}{Pr[C|D]\cdot Pr[D] +Pr[C|\bar{D}]\cdot Pr[\bar{D}]}.$

I thought cause the events are independent i can calculate  :$Pr[C|D]=\frac{Pr[C\cap{D}]}{Pr[D]}=\frac{1-(Pr[A\cap{B}])+Pr[A\cap{C}]+Pr[B\cap{C}])}{Pr[D]}=\frac{1-0.11}{0.4}$.

But i get a wrong probability value.

Comment: I dislike the terminology that is practicized in your question. You start with events A,B,C,D (what events actually?). Then you speak of "attempting an event". Is that a new kind of "event" then? Same thing bothers me if you speak "having a success in an event".

Comment: I have edited the questions ,is the terminology OK now?

Comment: Sure looks better, but I would rather call the interviews 1,2,3,4 and then e.g. define $C$ as the event that Alice succeeds in interview 3 (corresponding order). This to keep events and interviews apart. Btw, is the correct value $0.9\times0.8=0.72$ perhaps? (probability on not succeeding in interviews 1 and 2, so that also interview 4 must be done).

Comment: @drhab i think that working from the complement is easier so i thought to subtract the possibilities of Alice having succeeded in 2 interviews in the cases of A,B,C,D. $0.9\times0.8=0.72$ is the probability to fail A and B so Alice will try the C interview, but what i want tot calculate is the conditional probability of Alice passing the C interview and tries for D $Pr[C|D]$